# Excel workdays formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel 2010 formula that calculates delivery days on-time, late or early which is good but I need workdays, anyone know how to convert this formula?

```
=IF(AL16="","",TEXT(AL16-P29,"0 ""Day(s) Late"";0 ""Day(s) Early"";""On Time"""))
```

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you need ? I have no idea how to help you like this

Comment: Hakan / Darren, so much appreciate your help but not there yet?. Please see photo, if I add (NETWORKDAYS, then close brackets after or at end returns error message to few or too many arguments.  The source cells are dates, expected and actual delivery but calculation cell will only work for days not networkdays, appreciate any further advice, cheers Scott

Comment: Sorry cant add photo

Comment: @scott-g , `NETWORKDAYS` needs only 2 required parameters which both should be dates. Third parameter is optional and used if we have any unregular holidays other than weekends. Could you copy and paste your formula and what is inside `P29` and `AL16` cells, to your comment?

Comment: Hi Hakan, thank you.  The formula using easy cells A1, B1 and C1, is A1 is date format (*14 March 2001) of expected delivery, B1 is actual delivery date, and C1 to calculate whether on-time, early or late.  If in A1 = 18th April 2018, B2 = 20th April then C1 tells me "2 Day(s) late, okay, but if I then change B2 to 23rd April, C1 tells me 5 day(s) late not 3 as counts Sat/Sun.  C1 is =IF(B1="","",TEXT(B1-A1,"0 ""Day(s) Late"";0 ""Day(s) Early"";""On Time""")) . Cant figure out how/where to insert WORKDAYS to show '3 DAY(s) late'.  Great if you can solve this mystery, thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have your data sheet, it is not easy to understand what the formula is doing but assuming that `AL16-P29` part is an ordinary date difference, you should ammend that part to `NETWORKDAYS(P29, AL16)` in order to find how many workdays are there between these two dates.

As a result your formula s/b:

```
=IF(AL16="","",TEXT(NETWORKDAYS(P29, AL16),"0 ""Day(s) Late"";0 ""Day(s) Early"";""On Time"""))
```